# Doesn't IQueryable.Expression = Expression.Constant(this); cause an infinite loop?

Tags: linq

Expression trees represent code in a tree-like data structure, where each node is an expression. In Linq they are used by linq providers to convert them into native language of a  target process.

I know very little of expression trees, but I've been reading the following code where author uses `Expression.Constant(this)` to describe the initial query. Thus according to author `Expression.Constant(this)` should enable provider to retrieve the initial sequence of elements for `someQuery`.

But to my understanding this should instead cause an infinite loop, since expression tree in `someQuery.Expression` is describing `someQuery` object and not the details of the query itself ( or to put it differently, if target platform is SQL DB, `Expression.Constant(this)`  doesn't describe in non-sql terms which rows or tables a query should retrieve from a DB ). And thus when provider looks into `someQuery.Expression`, it will only find description **D** of `someQuery` object.And if it further inspects the details of **D.Expression** property, it again finds the description of `someQuery` object and so on – thus infinite loop:

```
    public class Query<T> : IQueryable<T>...
    {
        QueryProvider provider;
        Expression expression;

        public Query(QueryProvider provider) {
            this.provider = provider;
            this.expression = Expression.Constant(this);
        }
                     ...
    }

Query<string> someQuery = new Query<string>();
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect the provider to have knowledge of the query type and know that when it hit a constant expression of type `Query<T>`, it had hit a leaf, effectively. Sooner or later, the provider has to get to *something* describing "the whole table" or an equivalent. Of course the `Query<T>` would need the information about which table etc, but in a full example I'd expect it to have that information.

(Out of interest, am I the author in question? I wrote something very similar in C# in Depth...)

Comment: No, it's from the following link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/30/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i.aspx. I haven't read the whole article, but I don't think Query<T> has any information on which table data should come from - could you check it out and report back ;). Out of curiosity, does the Query<T> example in your book have "something" describing "the whole table"?

Comment: @user702769: In that situation, you could make the `Table<T>` itself the QueryProvider - the `Query<T>` still has a reference to the provider, so it could get back to the root that way. I can't remember what my small sample in C# in Depth does...

Comment: But the bottom line is, that Query<> should have some information on table and rows it should retrieve - perhaps in the form of properties?! Anyways, code from the link I've provided doesn't have anything like that, so I feel I'm still missing something very obvious?!

Comment: 2 - "you could make the Table<T> itself the QueryProvider - the Query<T> still has a reference to the provider, so it could get back to the root that way." Sorry, that went over my head. Doesn't Query<> already represent a table from DB? You're saying that in addition to Query<T> we could also have a Table<T> object, which would describe the DB table ( and particular rows from that table ) and also be a provider?

Comment: I'm saying that the `Query<T>` has a reference to the provider which created it - that provider can have all the information that's required.

Comment: @user702769: Don't forget that this is just *one* possible implementation. They're only interfaces, after all :)